# I have 2 PlayStation 4s. I want to keep my progress on a game on one and start from the beginning on another; will it let me?

Tags: ps4, psn

If I have two PlayStation 4s and one has a game on it with a bunch of progress and I re-download that same game onto another PlayStation 4 (using my PSN account) will it still keep my progress I had onto the first PlayStation and let me start from the beginning on my new one?

I am wondering this because I played a bunch of God of War 4 and I want to keep my progress onto my first PlayStation 4 and start from the beginning on another without messing anything up.

Comment: If you want 2 separate save files on the same account, make sure you don't have cloud save turned on and it won't overwrite your other save. I am not sure how it works with 2 ps4's but I assume you can turn it on for one console and turn it off for the other so they don't overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

Single player saves are usually stored locally on the console, so yes, you can keep your progress on one console and start a new save on a different one even while logged into the same PSN account.

An exception to this are games that store their save data on the developer's end, which is usually the case with online multiplayer games where you have a player profile, so your progression is associated with your PSN account and will be downloaded and synced when you start the same game on a different console.

You won't ever accidentally overwrite a save on a different console either way.

Within the same PSN account you can also copy and paste save data between your consoles by going to Settings -> Application Saved Data Management. You can either copy saves onto a USB-Stick or upload them to the PS Plus Cloud service (you need an active PS Plus subscription for the cloud option). So, if you ever do want to continue your progress for a game on a different console you also have the option to do that, but you'll have to do it manually.

If you're ever unsure or want to back up your saves, copy them onto a USB stick just in case.

Comment: it worked i did the USB thing just in case but it ended up working fine thanks